# How can I search npmjs.com packages on multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, npm, npmjs

How can I search packages on npmjs.com having two (or more) specific tags? I experimented with some search terms, but to no avail:

```
keywords:webpack+plugin
keywords:webpack,plugin
keywords:webpack keywords:plugin
```

The npmjs.com documentation also didn't give me an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the search from console.

```
npm find "kw1" "kw2"
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search

Answer (score 14):

Try to use space

```
keywords:kw1 kw2
```